# check chlauth for a MQ channel

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to check if any `chlauth` method is deployed for a channel or not in my MQ. So I run this command:

```
dis chlauth(MY.CHANNEL.NAME)
```

But I've got this message:

```
AMQ8884: Channel authentication record not found.
```

So, does it mean that I run a wrong command or it means that this channel has no channel authentication mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `CHLAUTH` rules can be put in place either with fully spelled out channel names, or with wild carded profiles, there are a few different ways to display the `CHLAUTH` rules in the system.

In this case the best way to determine whether there is a rule that will apply to your channel when it runs is to use the following command:

```
DISPLAY CHLAUTH(MY.CHANNEL.NAME) +
        MATCH(RUNCHECK) +
        ADDRESS(IP-address) +
        CLNTUSER(client-side-UserID)
```

You can read more about this approach in [I'm being blocked by CHLAUTH - how can I work out why?](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/blocked_by_chlauth_why/)